# Bokeh Python conditional CheckboxGroup

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

Is there an easy way to create a conditional `CheckboxGroup` within the `Bokeh`-framework? Conditional in the sense that when another `Bokeh`-widget is triggered, the `CheckboxGroup` is populated based on the value within the triggering widget.

So for instance, if I am having a dropdown-menu in form of a `Select`-widget with options `[a, b]`, and a separate Python-dict pointing at these "new" options `{'a' : ['aa','bb','cc'], 'b' : ['dd','ee','ff']}` - how do I create a checkbox based on the specific choice?

Pseudo code:

```
options_dict = {'a' : ['aa','bb','cc'], 'b' : ['dd','ee','ff']}
dropdown = Select(title="a dropdown menu:", options = ['a', 'b'], value='a')

# let all sub-options be the default option
checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff'], active=['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff'])

# assume we have some function that is updating and fetching the value of the 'dropdown'

def select_something():
    selected_attribute = dropdown.value()
    return selected_attribute

def update():
    selected_attribute = select_something()
    # update the CheckBox contents - obviously Pseudo-code
    checkbox.labels = options_dict[selected_attribute]
    # and have all of them "pre-checked"
    checkbox.active = options_dict[selected_attribute]

dropdown.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can update the checkboxgroup by changing its `active` parameter.

It is a list of integers refering to each checkbox in order, if you have 3 checkboxes and you want only the last one to be checked you would change the `active` list to `[2]`; if you just want the first and last one to be checked you would change it to `[0,2]`